# Wordpress - after installation, CSS files don't work

Tags: wordpress

I just created a new Wordpress project. I have managed to create a local domain to it, created db (without any data) and configurated my config.php (created from config.sample.php). Then I opened it in the browser to start the installation, but it is obviously broken - CSS is not working.

Please help, what can be wrong?

There is also another project where CSS files obviously don't work. I download that project from gitlab. That one was not from scretch. Both don't work correctly.

Comment: any logs, error messages to share ?

Comment: WP_Debug shown nothing. In console it looks like the problem could be that the links have https, not http.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when you have not entered the correct website address during WordPress installation.
This guide will help you with:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

If the site is in an active domain, send its address so that the problem can be checked.